# Alter Nested List of Tuples

Tags: c#, linq

I've variable declared as below

```
List<Tuple<TypeX, List<Tuple<TypeY, int, bool>>, int, int, int>> lst;
```

I wanted to alter the inside boolean variable using linq query.
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: That's not going to be easy.  Consider using a mutable class.

Comment: LINQ is all about querying and selecting data. It's not really good in updating and altering. However, could you describe your problem a bit more?

Comment: You probably want to reconsider your data design...

Comment: This data structure descriptions is as below

a) Tuple of TypeX which has some related objects

b) List<Tuple<TypeY, int, bool>> many TypeY, count and stats
c) 3 other counts per TypeX

I initialized the object by separating TypeY and the other inits

Comment: is there a reason you didn't use `List<CustomClass>`?, edit, didnt see lee had included this in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using linq, you'll need to create a new list with the transformed structure:

```
lst = lst.Select(t => Tuple.Create(
    t.Item1,
    t.Item2.Select(it => Tuple.Create(it.Item1, it.Item2, Transform(it.Item3))).ToList(),
    t.Item3,
    t.Item4,
    t.Item5
)).ToList();
```

where `Transform` is the operation to transform the inner boolean values.

I would consider creating a custom class for this rather than using tuples, since large tuples can be difficult to work with.